# Getting values of two editorFor values and adding them up to see if it meets condition

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a td in my row that includes an editorFor that looks like this

```
<td>
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Parts[i].Qty)
</td>
```

I have JQuery code that clones the row when a checkbox is clicked, my question is.. How can I add the value of the original EditorFor textbox to the value of the cloned editorFor textbox. In order to provide validation checks before the user submits the page.

Can this be done?

Here is my JQuery code that copies the row

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tr_clonePart input.part-class').change(function () {

                let Id = $(this).attr('id');
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
                //getting closest tr
                var selector = $(this).closest('.tr_clonePart');
                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                    // remove cloned row
                    $('#' + Id + 'clone').remove();

                    selector.find(".AllTxt").show();
                    selector.find(".editQty").hide();
                }
                else {
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clonePart');
                    var $clone = $tr.clone();
                    $clone.find('td');
                    $tr.after($clone);
                    $($clone).find(".part-class").hide();
                    //var qtyInItem = $('input[name=Parts['+partId+"].QtyInItem").val()


                    $clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", (i, n) => n + 'clone');
                    $clone.attr('id', (Id) + "clone");
                    var clonedID = Id + "clone";
                    $($clone).append($("<td class= 'addRow' ><a href=\"javascript:add('" + clonedID + "')\">add row</a></td>"));
            

                }

            });
```

Comment: Could you show the jQuery code that copies the checkbox?

Comment: @Achtung okay I added it in

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where you append your cloned checkbox but when cloning and appending the value of the checkbox comes along like in this example:

```js
var clonenbr = 0;
$(".add-checkbox").on("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  var clone = $($("td")[0]).clone()
  clone.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("name", (i, n) => n + 'clone' + clonenbr++);
  $("tr").append(clone)
 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="aa" value="a" />
aa
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>

<a href="#" class="add-checkbox">Add checkbox</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to append the checkbox. If the checkbox in the first row is checked. Then every cloned row would be an editorFor. I'm just wondering how to add the values of the editorFor's together in order to provide validation that the user did not succeed or go under the qtyInItem value